# stringstream operator>> fails to assign a number in debug

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iostream, stringstream, istream

I have this simple function that, given a string `str`, if it is a number then return 'true' and overwrite the reference input `num`.

```
template <typename T>
bool toNumber(string str, T& num)
{
    bool bRet = false;
    if(str.length() > 0U)
    {
        if (str == "0")
        {
            num = static_cast<T>(0);
            bRet = true;
        }
        else
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << str;
            ss >> num;    // if str is not a number op>> it will assign 0 to num
            if (num == static_cast<T>(0)) 
            {
                bRet = false;
            }
            else
            {
                bRet = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        bRet = false;
    }
    return bRet;
}
```

So I expect that:

```
int x, y;
toNumber("90", x); // return true and x is 90
toNumber("New York", y); // return false and let y unasigned.
```

On my machine, both debug and release configurations works fine, but on the server, only with the debug configuration, in calls like `toNumber("New York", y)` the 'ss >> num' fails to recognize that `str` is a string.

I checked the project configuration, but they are the same for both machines (the server is a svn-checkout of my local vs-2015 project).

I have literally no idea on how to solve the problem. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is made too complicated, you can simplify it to this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
bool toNumber(std::string str, T& num)
{
    return !!(std::istringstream { std::move(str) } >> num);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Pq5xGdof5

Ok I've missed that you wish to avoid zero assignment in case of failure (what streams do by default):

```cpp
template <typename T>
bool toNumber(std::string str, T& num)
{
    T tmp;
    std::istringstream stream{ std::move(str) };
    if (stream >> tmp) {
        num = tmp;
    }
    return !!stream;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nErqn3YYG

Comment: Nothing in the OP's question indicates that `num` should be left unassigned when `false` is returned. Doing so just introduces an unnecessary logic branch. Case in point, the OP's original code does zero-assign `num` if `str` is not empty or `"0"` and the stream fails.

Comment: In code comments are indicating that: `// return false and let y unasigned.` and `// if str is not a number op>> it will assign 0 to num`. Not very directly, but still. And when you think why his code is so complex this must be a root cause (for example this: `if (str == "0")` must be for that).

Comment: The way the OP's code is written, `return false and let y unasigned` is misleading, it is actually more like `return false and y may or may not be left unasigned` since `if str is not a number op>> it will assign 0 to num` is true. `y` would be left unassigned only if `str` is empty, but will be assigned `0` if `stringstream` fails. Not very consistent behavior. The comment should really be more like `return false and ignore y`

Answer (score 5):

Checking the value of the number that `operator>>` outputs is the wrong way to go.  You should check the `stringstream`'s failure state instead, eg:

```
template <typename T>
bool toNumber(string str, T& num)
{
    bool bRet = false;
    if (str.length() > 0U)
    {
        if (str == "0")
        {
            num = static_cast<T>(0);
            bRet = true;
        }
        else
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << str;
            if (ss >> num) // <--
            {
                bRet = true;
            }
            else
            {
                bRet = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        bRet = false;
    }
    return bRet;
}
```

`operator>>` returns a reference to the input stream, and the stream is implicitly convertible to `bool` in boolean contexts, like an `if` statement, where `true` means the stream is in a good state, and `false` means the stream is in a failed state.

In which case, you can *greatly* simplify the function much much further, by getting rid of the redundant `bRet` assignments, and the redundant input checks that the `stringstream` will already handle for you, eg:

```
template <typename T>
bool toNumber(const string &str, T& num)
{
    std::istringstream ss(str);
    return static_cast<bool>(ss >> num);
    // or:
    // return !!(ss >> num);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/ufwLVh)

Comment: Thanks for the hint but `return (ss >> num)` does not return a bool, then the compiler throw this error `'return': cannot convert from 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' to 'bool' `

Comment: Ok now with the cast works very fine! I will take this very-compact version. Thks so much!

Answer (score 0):

> `if (num == static_cast<T>(0))`

Bad idea. To know if `operator>>` failed, check the status of the stream.

```
if (ss >> num) { ...
```

Once you have this check in place, the (totally incorrect) piece

```
    if (str == "0")
    {
        num = static_cast<T>(0);
        bRet = true;
    }
```

becomes redundant, and

```
if(str.length() > 0U)
```

also becomes redundant, and then the whole thing simplifies to a line or two.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Inspired by this I changed the if statment from `if (num == static_cast<T>(0))` to `if (ss.fail())` and it works!

Comment: @GiaMat45 You really should use `if (ss >> num)` instead of `ss >> num; if (ss.fail())`

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, I agree with you and I will use the `>>` directly into the if. Thanks!